# Where do I place log4j.xml file for Swing based project in netbeans?

Tags: log4j

But, Can anyone here explain how one can configure log levels if its 'jar'ed.
I've no clue as to where do I place so that netbeans doesnt include this while creating the distribution jar. 'log4j.xml' should be outside the jar and programs should be able to read the levels configured from this file. I'm lil puzzled on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with NetBeans, so this piece of advice is rather generic: if you want the `log4j.xml` file to be used by log4j, but not included in jar, put it in a directory outside the scope of your project (a directory that is not packed into jar), and add this directory (directory, not file — important!) to the execution classpath of your program.

I hope you'll figure out how to achieve this in NetBeans. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you MaDa. I was facing difficulties when I placed log4j.xml outside the jar in reading the configuration. Thats the reason, I wanted to know if there are any specific ways.